# How to create dynamic lambda join query using expression in C#?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, expression-trees

I am new to dynamic expression query...

I want to create a join query dynamically. Below it the query for which I want the equivalent dynamic query:

```
var lstNums = new List<int> { 100, 101 }; 
var getAll = new StudenRepository().GetAll(); //Returns IQuerable<Student>

var query = getAll.Join(lstNums, a => a.StudentId, b => b, (a, b) => a).ToList();
```

1. The `lstNums` can be list of any primitive data types
2. The `getAll` contains IQuerable, this can be IQuerable of any entity
3. The `query` will contain the `List<Student>` records after doing join with the `getAll` and list of integers. But the result can be any list of entity. The list i.e. lstNum can be any list of primitive data types.

Below is what I have tried:

```
public static IQueryable JoinQuery(this IQueryable outer, IEnumerable innerEntities, string firstEntityPropName, 
    Type typeSecondEntity, Type typeResultEntity, params object[] values)
{
    LambdaExpression outerSelectorLambda = DynamicLinq.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(outer.ElementType, null, firstEntityPropName, values);

    ParameterExpression expnInput = Expression.Parameter(typeSecondEntity, "inner");
    ParameterExpression expnResult = Expression.Parameter(typeResultEntity, "outer");               

    return outer.Provider.CreateQuery(
       Expression.Call(
           typeof(Queryable), "Join",
           new Type[] { outer.ElementType, innerEntities.AsQueryable().ElementType, outerSelectorLambda.Body.Type, expnResult.Type },
           outer.Expression, innerEntities.AsQueryable().Expression, Expression.Quote(outerSelectorLambda), expnInput,
           expnResult));
}
```

The extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> JoinQuery<T>(this IQueryable outer, IEnumerable innerEntities, string firstEntityPropName, Type typeSecondEntity, Type typeResultEntity, params object[] values)
{
    return (IQueryable<T>)Extensions.JoinQuery((IQueryable)outer, (IEnumerable)innerEntities, firstEntityPropName, typeSecondEntity, typeResultEntity, values);
}
```

**Note:** I have installed `System.Linq.Dynamic` nuget package version `1.0.7` for dynamic linq expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code worked for me:

```
using DynamicLinq = System.Linq.Dynamic;
using LinqExpression = System.Linq.Expressions;

public static IQueryable JoinQuery(this IQueryable outer, IEnumerable innerEntities, string firstEntityPropName, 
    Type typeSecondEntity, Type typeResultEntity, params object[] values)
{
    if (innerEntities == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(innerEntities));
    if (firstEntityPropName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(firstEntityPropName));
    if (typeSecondEntity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(typeSecondEntity));
    if (typeResultEntity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(typeResultEntity));

    LambdaExpression outerSelectorLambda = DynamicLinq.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(outer.ElementType, null, firstEntityPropName, values);

    ParameterExpression expnInput = Expression.Parameter(typeSecondEntity, "inner");

    ParameterExpression[] parameters = new ParameterExpression[] {
    Expression.Parameter(outer.ElementType, "outer"), Expression.Parameter(innerEntities.AsQueryable().ElementType, "inner")
    };

    LambdaExpression selectorSecondEntity = DynamicLinq.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new ParameterExpression[] { expnInput }, typeSecondEntity, "inner");
    LambdaExpression selectorResult = DynamicLinq.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(parameters, typeResultEntity, "outer");

    return outer.Provider.CreateQuery(
       Expression.Call(
           typeof(Queryable), "Join",
           new Type[] { outer.ElementType, innerEntities.AsQueryable().ElementType, outerSelectorLambda.Body.Type, selectorResult.Body.Type },
           outer.Expression, innerEntities.AsQueryable().Expression, Expression.Quote(outerSelectorLambda), Expression.Quote(selectorSecondEntity),
          Expression.Quote(selectorResult)));
}
```

The extension method is as follows:

```
public static IQueryable<T> JoinQuery<T>(this IQueryable outer, IEnumerable innerEntities, string firstEntityPropName, Type typeSecondEntity, Type typeResultEntity, params object[] values)
{
    return (IQueryable<T>)Extensions.JoinQuery((IQueryable)outer, (IEnumerable)innerEntities, firstEntityPropName, typeSecondEntity, typeResultEntity, values);
}
```